# How to transfer Minecraft PE Worlds from Android to iPhone

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I just got a new iPhone, and after downloading Minecraft on it, I wanted to transfer my Minecraft worlds from my Android tablet to my iPhone. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

### From my knowledge, no.

Android and IOS device are two different devices, and if you have tried to edit any files on the IOS device, it's more complicated than the Android. I don't think you can even transfer worlds between the same devices on IOS, making it far less likely to transfer them between IOS and Android. Hey, I could be wrong though. :P

Comment: As of recent updates it is now possible between iOS and android.